# shared auth (single sign-on) across app based on different rails versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, single-sign-on

Currently I develop new app for my customer and need to integrate it with the old one.
My current app based on `Ruby 1.9.3` and latest Rails version. Old app written on `Ruby 1.8.7` and something like `rails 3.0.11.`

I'm interested, how I can allow my app reuse auth logic from the old one. So if user already login in the old app, my application should think that user already login in my app also. Old app use standard rails auth mechanism.

So the perfect variant for me will be just accept token and cookies from the old aplication.